# Drive API v2 & v3 (1.16) File Watch requests being denied when using Batch Request

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm getting 403 watchDenied errors when I try to make File Watch requests in a Batch Request. Sending them normally is fine. I'm presuming that batching of File Watch requests is permitted?

Additional info: If I set an incorrect Address, I get the usually unpermitted webhook address error, and if I set a dummy file ID I get a 404, so it doesn't feel like the request I'm making is incorrect.

Example code (using the C# client library):

```
var request = new BatchRequest(service);
request.Queue<Channel>(service.Files.Watch(
    new Channel
    {
        Id = [Guid being used],
        Type = "web_hook",
        Address = [notification endpoint],
        Token = [token being used],
        Expiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
    }, fileId)
    , (content, error, i, message) =>
    {

    }
);
await request.ExecuteAsync();
```

**API Request**

Headers:

```
POST: https://www.googleapis.com/batch
User-Agent: OverDRIVE google-api-dotnet-client/1.16.0.0 (gzip)
Authorization: Bearer [token]
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="8d7a0653-4d9b-4c09-b701-9794341f882d"
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 988
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Body:

```
--8d7a0653-4d9b-4c09-b701-9794341f882d
Content-Type: application/http

POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[fileId]/watch
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length:  241

{"address":"[notification endpoint]","expiration":1474036096103,"id":"938bd983-b071-4e63-8535-f20d7f39e248","token":"[token being used]","type":"web_hook"}

--8d7a0653-4d9b-4c09-b701-9794341f882d
Content-Type: application/http

POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[fileId]/watch
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length:  241

{"address":"[notification endpoint]","expiration":1474036096105,"id":"79303874-5f6c-49aa-a601-93950895ac0f","token":"[token being used]","type":"web_hook"}

--8d7a0653-4d9b-4c09-b701-9794341f882d--
```

**Error example**

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "push",
    "reason": "watchDenied",
    "message": "Watch request denied by backend"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Watch request denied by backend"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had an update from the developer support team for a ticket I submitted to them.

> Unfortunately watch requests are known to largely incompatible with
>   Drive batch requests. Our Drive team recommended to make watch
>   requests separate from other requests.